# Radio button Office Excel 2013

Tags: excel, radio-button, vba

I'm making a questionnaire to estimate risks and impacts for work.
Basically, the person that opens the questionnaire reads different questions and answers using drop-down lists I put in place.

I added 2 radio buttons at the top that offers the document in either French or English. The answers in the drop-down lists are linked to another tab that return either the answer in French or in English depending on the radio button that is currently selected.

Situation:
I choose all my answers in French first then click on the English radio button. It switches all my answers to English. When I click the French radio button after, all my answers stay in English. Same thing happens if I start in English then switch to French then switch to English again, all my answers stay in French.

I need to fix this problem because my answers are linked to values and when the French radio button is selected, I can only get the value of the answer if it's in French. Same thing for the English button.

Comment: Without the code is hard to predict what's happening. What I think it could be happening -by the text I can infer it's in a UserForm- is that you don't have the "translator"  routine called properly to handle translations after performed the first time.

Comment: Oh i see. Is it possible to link my file on here? (in a comment or message)
Where do I go to call that "translator"?
I did it manually by putting "if"s so that way if the 'french' button is selected, it returns the answer in french, else it returns the answer in english. So I don't know if I'm actually using it the appropriate way.

Comment: Please, take a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Use code tags for your code.

Comment: Where do you suggest I host my file so I can then link it?

Comment: You can share your file using (eg) DropBox

Comment: Ok thanks.
Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mh726xmz5dl6wiy/AACh2I-5O1JIL88z4m2z-T7Ba?dl=0 
The buttons are in the tab 'Evaluation' and the values are in the tab 'Valeurs' which link to the tabs 'Valeurs FR' and 'Valeurs EN'.

Comment: Another problem I seem to have is that when I protect the sheet that I am on, I can't click on the radio buttons anymore because it says that they are locked yet I didn't lock them so I don't know why I'm getting this message.